# Migrating an Enum in Vapor using AsyncMigration

Tags: swift, enums, fluent, vapor

How would one migrate an `enum` using `AsyncMigration`? There are a few examples online of migrating one using the `EventLoopFuture`, but my preference is to use Swift Concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of debugging, I was able to get everything working using `AsyncMigration`. I also find it a bit cleaner to read than using an `EventLoopFuture`.

Suppose we want to add an `enum` representing user roles:

```swift
public enum Role: String, Codable, Equatable {
    case appUser = "app_user"
    case admin = "admin"
}
```

You'd create a Fluent model and add the field:

```swift
@Enum(key: "role")
var role: Role
```

Lastly, you'd want to migrate it in two steps:

```swift
struct CreateUsers: AsyncMigration {

    func prepare(on database: Database) async throws {
        let role = try await database.enum("role")
            .case(User.Role.appUser.rawValue)
            .case(User.Role.admin.rawValue)
            .create()
        try await database.schema(User.schema)
            .id()
            // ...
            .field("role", role, .required, .custom("DEFAULT '\(User.Role.appUser.rawValue)'"))
            .create()
    }
    
    func revert(on database: Database) async throws {
        try await database.enum("role").delete()
        try await database.schema(User.schema).delete()
    }

}
```

I prefer to use the `rawValue`, to ensure everything is Strongly bound.

Also note I added `.custom("DEFAULT '\(User.Role.appUser.rawValue)'")` to the `field` initializer. This will default the database's column to be an `app_user` (optional).

Comment: Remember to delete the enum in the `revert` method after deleting the table.  `database.enum("role").delete()`. And also if you confirm the enum to `caseIteratable` you can access all the enum fields via `User.Role.allCases()` and create the enums fields

Comment: @HadiSharghi good call, I will update my answer accordingly!